# Man, silk, particle? — Oh my, what a combination!

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking

> Follow my words
>   to form one.
>
> Many a man
>
> Soft, twilled silk
>   A chapter of the Quran
>   Distinct repetition!
>   Omit the trailing sound
>
> Charged particle
>   Add a letter
>   to make it fit,
>   Suffix!
>
> Add the three groups
>   Tada, a mathematical term!
>
> Either a misspelling
>   or a misinterpretation
>   might make it womanly;
>   beware—you do not intend offense.

### What is the word, may I ask?

Comment: Are you certain that the cryptic-crosswords tag is appropriate?

Comment: Yes, unless I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Your cryptic-clues tag was inappropriate as well. Please make sure if this is the right tag.

Comment: I guess this works as Crossword Clues rather than cryptic crosswords. Cryptic crosswords/clues have stringent rules. This fits more like a standard crossword clues you find in a newspaper.

Comment: Guys, thanks for answering and understanding. It's the 2nd riddle I ever made in my whole life. This day I made another riddle before, which is way more harder. Do try it out! I'm only 13 and very new to Puzzling, so please try to co-operate with me.

Comment: Ok, if this is your second riddle, I must say, I am impressed! You have done really well. Do contribute wholeheartedly to this site with lots more and better puzzles. :-)

Comment: @Sid You have seen and commented upon my 1st riddle too, as far as I remember. I'M FIRE; I COMPRESS. Thanks, anyways. I will try to give my best to this site.

Comment: I'm 13 too here, and I can see you've made an effort (+1). This is a very good effort, and I hope to see more of these from you in the future, I know it's late, but Welcome to Puzzling :)

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine If you want to keep it secret delete that comment (everyone else can see it). Also I can't answer a question that has an accepted answer with the same answer :). Try taking the [tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and maybe have a look at some of the [highest voted questions](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) to help you. Good luck!

Comment: Ok. If you want to chat with people on site then there is the chat room [the sphinx's lair](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52151/discussion-between-soha-farhin-pine-and-beastly-gerbil).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer must be

> MENSURATION.

Many a man

> MEN

Soft, twilled silk
A chapter of the Quran

> Former is SURAH (a word I confess I didn't know before), latter is also SURAH, alternately spelled without the trailing H.

Distinct repetition!

> SURAH both times. An obvious repetition.

Omit the trailing sound

> ...yielding SURA.

Charged particle

> ION

Add a letter to make it fit,
Suffix!

> Add a 'T' to make -TION, a common suffix.

Add the three groups
Tada, a mathematical term!

> First line refers to three groups of letters (i.e. MEN, SURA, TION). Concatenate those three parts together to get MENSURATION, which *is* a  mathematical term.

Either a misspelling
or a misinterpretation
might make it womanly;
beware—you do not intend offense.

> Confusion with MENSTRUATION.

Comment: I see OP has edited my answer, with comment "Corrected a slight logic problem". I must (gently) protest. I removed AH/A from the end of SURAH/SURA, which does indeed remove a "trailing sound", whereas what's there now removes only the H which is silent. (I then removed "a T" rather than a "T"; obviously either of those is fine in isolation.) And there is an important distinction between "three groups" and "groups of three".

Comment: The first word SURAH is always spelled with a H at the end. The second word, can be written as either SURA or SURAH. Since you know that both should be the same (`Distinct repetition!`), you should take SURAH, which is a correct word for both. Omit the trailing 'sound' --- yes, the sound seems to be the root of the confusion and misunderstanding. It appears to be slightly misleading, but I tried not to be too obvious.

Comment: I interpreted "distinct" as "different from one another", so a distinct repetition is where you have two things that are kinda the same but not quite. Like SURAH and SURA. It's the same sound that's being removed from both, after all :-).

Comment: Well, you were right in that sense. But, distinct here means 'clear' or 'obvious'.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here it is:

> Mensuration:

Many a man

> Men

Soft, twilled silk

> surah

A chapter of the Quran

> Surah

Distinct repetition!

> Surah because both are same

Omit the trailing sound

> Sura? (Ignoring the last h)

Charged particle

> Ion

Add a letter to make it fit,
Suffix!

> We add T which does not have a sound.

Add the groups of three
Tada, a mathematical term!

> Mensuration

Either a misspelling
or a misinterpretation
might make it womanly;

> Menstruation

beware—you do not intend offense.